# Determine the value of $ \frac{1}{\log_m (mn)}+\frac {1}{\log_n (mn)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Determine the value of $\dfrac{1}{\log_m (mn)}+\dfrac{1}{\log_n (mn)}$.

The answer sheet says the answer is $1$, can't seem to understand why, please explain

Comment: Does your $log(a)b$ mean $\log_a b$? (Use <code>\log_a b</code> for the latter notation.)

Comment: yes, i'm new to this and do not know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \log_m n$. Then $\log_m mn = \log_m m + \log_m n = 1 + x$ and $\log_n mn = \log_n n + \log_n m = 1 + \frac1x$. Therefore
$$\frac{1}{\log_m mn} + \frac{1}{\log_n mn} = \frac{1}{1 + x} + \frac{1}{1 + \frac1x} = \frac{1}{1 + x} + \frac{x}{x + 1} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong, for example take $m=n=e$. You have $\log(m)=\log(n)=1$ and finally :
$$\frac 1{\log(m) mn}+\frac 1{\log(n) mn}=\frac 1 {e^2}+\frac 1 {e^2}=\frac 2{e^2}\neq1$$

---

If you mean :
$$\frac 1{\log_m(mn)}+\frac 1{\log_n (mn)}=\frac {\log(m)}{\log(mn)}+\frac {\log(n)}{\log(mn)}=\frac{\log(m)+\log(n)}{\log(mn)}=\frac{\log(mn)}{\log(mn)}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ so that $$\dfrac{1}{\log(n)mn}+\dfrac{1}{\log(m)mn}=\dfrac{\log(m)}{\log(m)\log(n)mn}+\dfrac{\log(n)}{\log(n)\log(m)mn}=\dfrac{\log(m)+\log(n)}{\log(m)\log(n)mn}=\dfrac{\log(mn)}{\log(m)\log(n)mn}$$
which is not necessarily $1$. For example, for any base $b\neq1,\sqrt{2}$, take $m=n=b$ and it's $\frac{2}{b^2}$

**Edit**: you said in a comment that $\log(m)mn=\log_{m}(mn)$. In that case, we have $$\dfrac{1}{\log_m(mn)}+\dfrac{1}{\log_n(mn)}=\dfrac{1}{\log_m(m)+\log_m(n)}+\dfrac{1}{\log_n(n)+\log_n(m)}=\dfrac{1}{1+\log_m(n)}+\dfrac{1}{1+\log_n(m)}$$
Then, notice that $$1+\log_n(m)+1+\log_m(n)=(1+\log_n(m))(1+\log_m(n))\cdot\left[\dfrac{1}{1+\log_n(m)}+\dfrac{1}{1+\log_m(n)}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{\log_{m} mn}+\frac{1}{\log_{n} mn}
  &= \frac{\log m}{\log mn}+\frac{\log n}{\log_{n} mn} \\
  &= \frac{\log m}{\log m+\log n}+\frac{\log n}{\log m+\log n} \\
  &= 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The formulas to use: $\log_a b = \frac{1}{\log_b a}$ and $\log_a b+\log_a c =\log_a (bc)$.

Thus: $\frac{1}{\log_m mn}+\frac{1}{\log_n mn}=\log_{mn} m +\log_{mn} n=\log_{mn} mn=1.$